# Drupal select module

Tags: 7

I am writing a module that contains two drop-down lists that are retrieved from a database:

- DDL 1: Region
- DDL 2: Territory

When I choose a region, I need it to have its own territory.

```
function alter_territory(&$form, &$form_state) { 
    $territory_options = array();
    $territory_options = filter_territories($Region);
    $form['name']['Region']['#ajax'] = array( 'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'territory-wrapper', 
    'callback' => 'filter_territories_callback', 
    'method' => 'replace', );
    $form['name'][''territory']['#prefix'] = '<div id="'territory-wrapper">';
    $form['name']['territory']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['name']['territory']['#options'] = $territory_options;
}

function filter_territories_callback($form, $form_state) {
    $Region = $form['name']['Region']['#value'];
    $form['name']['territory']['#options'] = filter_territories($Region);
    return $form['territory'];
}

function filter_territories($Region) { 
    $select = oci_parse($conn,select code,descr1 from db.table1 where code = $city);
    oci_execute($select);
    $territory = array();
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($select,OCI_ASSOC)) {
        $territory[$row['CODE']] = $row['Desc1'];
    }

    return $territory;
}
```

What could make the code work incorrectly?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What is exactly `alter_territory()`? If it is an implementation of `hook_form_alter()` then the function name is not correct; if it is not an implementation of `hook_form_alter()`, then you should show the code that calls that function. Also, in `$form['name'][''territory']['#prefix']` a string is not correctly delimited (`''territory'`).

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if this code is actually cut-and-pasted you should definitely get an application that does code highlighting to help you out. I (and many others) use [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html), but there are other free ones like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), and I'm sure others can help you find the right one. Code highlighting will help with your syntax problems big time and ultimately increase your productivity.

Comment: Also, be sure to check out the [Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) modules which have great Ajax examples to help you out.

Comment: You should definitely add a description of what's going wrong. It's difficult to help when we don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
function filter_territories($Region) { 
  $select = oci_parse($conn,select code,descr1 from db.table1 where code = $city);
  oci_execute($select);
  $territory = array();
  while ($row = oci_fetch_array($select,OCI_ASSOC)) {
    $territory[$row['CODE']] = $row['Desc1'];
  }

  return $territory;
}
```

The first argument passed to `oci_parse()` is a variable that is not passed as argument, nor is it declared as global variable; that variable is not containing any useful value for the function.
The second argument of that function should be a string, which is not what you are passing; it's probable that you are getting a syntax error there.
The argument passed to the function is not used.

```
$form['name'][''territory']['#prefix'] = '<div id="'territory-wrapper">';
```

The string `''territory'` is using two delimiters; it's probable that PHP is reporting a syntax error, there too.

The correct line should be the following one.

```
$form['name']['territory']['#prefix'] = '<div id="territory-wrapper">';
```

```
function filter_territories_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $Region = $form['name']['Region']['#value'];
  $form['name']['territory']['#options'] = filter_territories($Region);
  return $form['territory'];
}
```

From the shown code, the function is returning a part of the form that has not been defined. The form defines `$form['name']`, not `$form['territory']`.

I think you are not showing all the code; if you did show all the code you are using, then the `alter_territory()` function is not correctly named, which is a problem if that function is a hook implementation.

Comment: The territory-wrapper div has a syntax error with quotations as well.

Comment: Yes, it does. There are two strings in that line that have problems with the string delimiters.